# Is there a way to do a boolean union on many objects at the same time?

Tags: modifiers

Is there a way to do a boolean union on many objects at the same time?

I've recently finished the donut tutorial series and want to do a 3D print of the final product. I'm planing to print the donut as one object and the icing and decorations as a seperate one (I have made the decoration instances real). In order to make this work I'm trying to union the icing and decorations collection, but blender will not acept the collection as the target for the operation, though it will let me do it on one decoration on it's own. Is there a way of doing a Boolean on a colletion?

Thanks for the help. Both the solutions surgested work :)

Comment: There is an _Operand Type_ > _Collection_ in the _Boolean_ modifier, is it not working with your collection? Only from reading your words I'm not sure if I understand what's going on there to prevent it from working...

Comment: Ohhh. I hadn't noticed that option *face palm* yes it works if I set it to collections, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to quickly combine multiple different objects with union boolean operations is with Blender's handy pre-installed Bool Tool addon.

To activate the addon, simply go to the top left of the Blender window, select edit, and from the drop down menu select preferences at the bottom. Then go to the Addons panel of the preferences menu, and type "Bool" into the search bar.

Activate the Bool Tools addon, select the triangle drop down to expand the addon info, and make note of the shortcut/hotkey to use the addon.

[image]

Now with it turned on, you can then select all your objects you want to combine. Use the hotkey (in my case on mac its Ctrl+Shift+B), then select union.

[image]

Comment: You should probably mention that this is the destructive way of doing it, already applying the _Boolean_ modifier and **deleting** the other objects - which might not be desired. And using the non-destructive way with the _Bool Tool_ does it with each object individually, not with a collection - which is much more handy if you want to add objects to the collection afterwards.