How to combine multiple shells
(Forgive me for what is surely a very basic question, but I can't seem to find an answer.)
I have an STL file that contains multiple overlapping (water-tight) shells. I would like to boolean union these shells into a single mesh, but I can't figure out how to select the individual shells so that I can then try to boolean union them. I only seem to be able to select the entire model. This model was exported from Rhino, and is made up of a few hundred individual shapes.
I've tried the various items in the "select" menu to no avail. Blender seems unable to see any sub parts to my model.

I tried the method suggested by @GordonBrinkmann. It worked well except for some holes that appeared as you can see here:

And when I exported the resulting stl to Rhino, additional holes appeared in the flat rim (holes that don't show up in Blender):

I then tried using the same technique on a version of the model lacking the flat rim. This diminished but did not eliminate holes, as you can see here (on the lower right part of the model):


Your 'shells' have to be separate objects before you can boolean them. Please add an image of your stl file after you've imported it into Blender using Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu.

Please edit your original question and add the image into that. How to upload an image to a post. That way it will remain available for anyone wanting to look at the question in future.

@JohnEason Thanks, I have added the image to my question.

@JohnEason When you are using Geometry Nodes they do not have to be separated.

@GordonBrinkmann True but the poster appears to be a newcomer to Blender so probably isn't even aware of Geometry Nodes, let alone how to use them!

@John That image shows (in the top-right Outliner) that you have a single object so the normal Boolean operator has nothing to work on. However, Gordon's answer should give you a result. The alternative is to go into Edit mode with your object and try hitting P > Separate By Loose Parts. You should find that each 'shell' is then a separate object when you go back into Object mode and you could try using the boolean modifier. That would be very tedious though.

@JohnEason Sure, I thought that's why we are are teaching them solutions here ;)

@GordonBrinkmann :^)  I'll have to try reading the manual sometime. I'd never used the Mesh Boolean node, let alone realised that it could be used on a single object!

@JohnEason Admittedly I don't even kow if this is documented somewhere, I just discovered this a long while ago by working with it. It seems in order to prepare the first geometry object plugged in there to be combined in one way or the other, everything gets merged into a single mesh.

It's not mentioned in the 4.1 Manual or any of the YT tutorials as far as I can see although I've not been right through all of them yet.

@JohnEason Thanks! I was able to separate the parts as you describe. I then turned on the "bool tool" addon (which allow boolean operations on multiple objects), and performed the boolean union. Unfortunately, the results were not good. Most of the faceted elements disappeared in the process. I'm not sure whether I should post the image to my original question. I'm also not completely sure whether comments are the proper place for me to reply to you.

@GordonBrinkmann Thanks! As John Eason surmised, I'm a complete newbie to Blender, and am not familiar with Geometry Nodes, so I don't know how to attempt your suggested solution. Given that the boolean operation failed, do you think it's likely that your method will succeed for my model? BTW, FYI, the reason I'm attempting this is that the 3D printing service I've been using has suddenly decided that this model is unprintable due to having multiple shells. This despite the fact that they've successfully printed it for me numerous times before.

@John The normal Bool Tool addon doesn't allow boolean operations on multiple objects so I'm not sure what you are using? If you're getting poor results you could try selecting the Fast Solver button on the Boolean Modifier panel and also check Hole Tolerant in the Solver Options drop down section but I'd suspect that Gordon's method would probably work better with your original single object.

@JohnEason Thanks! I followed these instructions, but since the results were bad, I guess it doesn't matter: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301309/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-boolean-union-on-many-objects-at-the-same-time. I'll have to try to figure out how to use Gordon's method, which will be challenging given my lack of knowledge

@John Yes, my method will succeed with your model. Well, I cannot tell 100% since I do not have your model, but if it is just a bunch of meshes lumped together with overlapping geometry, this should work because that is basically what my example mesh is as well. I've added a step by step guide what I've done in Geometry Nodes, but I recommend you watch some tutorials on GN, you can really do a lot of stuff with it.

@GordonBrinkmann Thanks for the very clear instructions! I've described the mixed results I obtained above. (I did this by editing my original question but I'm not sure whether that's the proper protocol on this forum). Any ideas for how to address this problem. (The original stl definitely had no holes in it.)

There is a quite handy option with the Geometry Nodes modifier. If you just connect the input geometry with a Mesh Boolean node: no matter which combination mode you choose (Difference, Intersect or Union), if this is the only geometry you plug in it will be merged together to a single mesh. Afterwards you can apply the modifier and have the merged mesh. Depending on how complex and/or maybe tiny some overlapping parts are the mesh might need a little manual cleanup afterwards.
GN nodetree:

And this is a cross section to show the inside before and after using the Mesh Boolean:

Here some additional information how to get there since you mentioned you are not familiar with Geometry Nodes:

Open the Geometry Node Editor window and click on the New button. The object should be selected for the following steps.


The New button adds a Geometry Nodes modifier in the modifiers tab of the object and gives you the default nodetree: a Group Input node which provides the original mesh connected to a Group Output node which outputs as visible geometry whatever you generate with nodes plugged inbetween there.


Now add a new node with Shift+A > Add > Mesh > Operations > Mesh Boolean.


Place it between the Group Input and Group Output nodes - it should connect with them automatically. If not, connect the Geometry socket from the Group Input with the Mesh 1 input and the Mesh output with the Geometry socket on the Group Output node.


Depending on how complex your geometry is it might take a while to calculate the merged geometry and Blender might become unresponsive (at least on my old computer), but as soon as it is finished you can apply the modifier by going to the modifiers tab and pressing Ctrl+A with your mouse hovering over the modifier. Or you click on the drop down menu and choose Apply from there. That's it, the geometry is merged and you can export it as STL.



